# How to make every grid item the same width/height when one of them has an image child?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been trying to get familiar with grid while making the sidebar, and I encountered the problem where my grid items/children aren't equal to each-other in height even though they're supposed to be the same size.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
  height: 500px;
  gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-template: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: start;
}

.mainContainer div {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.mainContainer img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div> <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1455185376876826625/s1AjSxph_400x400.jpg"> </div>
  <div> Box 1 </div>
  <div> Box 2 </div>
  <div> Box 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the image

```
.mainContainer img{
  height: 30px; // set it to any size
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

I think you should use px instead of %

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah that works but I want it to be responsive so I was wondering if I could do it with a percentage.

Comment: it is responsive i ran it on jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah, just tried it as well. I'm guessing the img parent container div, makes it responsive because of the width and height percentage that I've set. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it is done without grid, but with a flex-column.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .mainContainer{
      height: 500px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 30px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .mainContainer > * {
      height: 25%;
      width: 60%;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      /* center image / text in children boxes */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .mainContainer img {
      object-fit: contain;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just become a problem with width instead? I wanted this section as some sort of sidebar done with grid so I don't think that making it into a column is possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the task. Wait a minute, I will change my response.